# Access 2010 VBA: Modificar el recordset que alimenta a un informe

Tags: vba, ms-access

Tengo un informe al que quiero cambiarle el recordset que lo alimenta desde VBA, así que desde el formulario del botón que lo alimenta, selecciono una consulta llamada OTaller y la acoto a los registros que tengan determinado Id

`filtro = "SELECT OTaller.*"
           filtro = filtro & " FROM OTaller"
           filtro = filtro & " WHERE Id=" & Me!Id.Value`

Luego, abro el report. Así:

`DoCmd.OpenReport "ordentallerSobre", acViewPreview, , filtro`

El resultado es un error. Lo que quisiera es que el report sólo mostrara los registros de OTaller que tengan ese Id, pero nada más. ¿Alguna idea?

Comment: Cuando dices que quieres cambiar el Recordset que lo alimenta, ¿Te refieres a simplemente a aplicar un filtro? ¿O a que mire los datos en otro sitio? Es que no es lo mismo, y dependiendo de lo que necesites, necesitarás un código u otro. Sí te puedo decir, que ahora mismo te da error, porque tu variable filtro debería tener solamente la cláusula WHERE, no la sentencia SQL completa.

Answer (score 0):

Buen Dia/Tarde/Noche:

Segun entiendo tu pregunta, es un filtro simple, con una clausula WHERE unicamente, pero, hay un error en tu WHERE justamente, de entrada te recomiendo que no formatees tu consulta en el codigo de visual de esa forma cuando son consultas demasiado cortas, por que sucede lo que te ocurrio, siento que te confundiste un poco, es bueno hacerlo pero solo cuando tienes una consulta grande, con JOINS que quieras asignar a algun control como source, tu consulta debio quedar de la siguiente manera:

```
filtro = "SELECT OTaller.* " & _
         "FROM OTaller " & _
         "WHERE Id = " & Nz(Me.Id, 0) & " "
```

Te explico; en lo personal me gusta formatear las consultas hasta en el codigo de visual, pero eso ya es de cada quien, mucho cuidado con las sangrias, si vas a hacer lo mismo, te recomiendo los saltos de linea, en consultas largas con JOINS no es muy recomendable, ya que el visual solo te da cierto numero de saltos de linea a colocar, por lo tanto esta correcto el formato que le diste a tu consulta originalmente, pero como en este caso es una consulta muy corta, tubo que haber quedado de la manera que te la puse arriba, con respecto a tu sintaxis como buena practica, te recomiendo el uso de la funcion Not Zero o "NZ()" con esta controlas algun error de nulo inesperado, y por ultimo, me llamo la atencion que utilizaste:

```
filtro = "SELECT OTaller.* "
```

Esto solo es un comentario sin relevancia, pero si solo estas consultando a una tabla, y mandas a llamar en la consulta a todos los campos, basta con:

```
filtro = "SELECT * "
```

La forma en la que lo utilizas es una buena practica cuando utilizas JOINS, es correcto como lo usas, pero puede llegar a confundir a alguien diferente a ti que le toque refactorizar tu codigo.